# How to make wc work recursively WITHOUT FIND

Tags: linux, recursion, ls, wc

I want to count letters in files. They are on different levels.
I used

```
wc -m `ls -R`
```

however, it works only for files that are in current directory. I need either to list full paths or extend wc scope.

I tried using

```
ls -d -1 $PWD/*
```

as several other answers suggest, but it is not recursive in any way. It prints as many levels as are typed with /* /* /*. It is not universal.

Comment: What is the problem with `find`?

Comment: And what of paths and file names with spaces in them and all the [other really good reasons to never use the output of `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-do-to-instead) in a downstream command?

Comment: I don't know if it's allowed here, but it's my assignment that i received in class. I did everything month ago except this one. I have nothing against find but my teacher said "we don't use find here. try experimenting". And that's the only reason why i can't present him my work .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you don't want to use `find`, but using `zsh` you can do:

```
 wc -l prometheus/**/*.{yml,json}                                                                                                                                                 
     9 prometheus/prometheus/alertmanager/config.yml
   104 prometheus/prometheus/docker-compose.yml
   103 prometheus/prometheus/docker-prometheus.dockerapp/docker-compose.yml
    99 prometheus/prometheus/docker-stack.yml
    11 prometheus/prometheus/grafana/provisioning/dashboards/dashboard.yml
    50 prometheus/prometheus/grafana/provisioning/datasources/datasource.yml
    66 prometheus/prometheus/prometheus/prometheus.yml
   114 prometheus/prometheus/pwd-stack.yml
    30 prometheus/prometheus.yml
   614 prometheus/prometheus/dashboards/Grafana_Dashboard.json
  1237 prometheus/prometheus/dashboards/Grafana_Dashboard_prom_2.json
   749 prometheus/prometheus/dashboards/System_Monitoring.json
   689 prometheus/prometheus/Grafana_Dashboard.json
   712 prometheus/prometheus/Grafana Dashboard With Service.json
  1581 prometheus/prometheus/grafana/provisioning/dashboards/Docker Prometheus Monitoring-1533038455876.json
   258 prometheus/prometheus/HighLoadDashboard.json
```

Comment: Sorry, but my working environment is bash.
I definitely want to use find. But my teacher goes all against it. When i ask him for hints he sends me away and says "try experimenting".

Comment: I have just discovered that putty supports what you've said. Thank you for curing my headache.